# trying to use $_SESSION['Auth']['User']['id'] in beforefilter()

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying to use `$_SESSION['Auth']['User']['id']` in `beforefilter()` function in `app_controller.php`. But I'm getting error message.
 Error message is -> `Undefined variable: _SESSION [APP\app_controller.php`
Here is my app_controller file. thanks

```
     `class AppController extends Controller {
         var $components = array('Acl', 'Session', 'Auth');
         ....................................`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$this->Auth->user('id')`, not the `$_SESSION` variable.
If you insist on reading from the session directly, use `$this->Session->read('Auth.User.id')`.

`$_SESSION` *should* be accessible, but that depends on when the session gets started and whether you're using PHP's session management at all. Use Cake's wrappers, they take care of those details.

Comment: I'm getting id from `$this->Auth->user('id');` not from `$this->Session->read('Auth.User.id')`. Whats the difference between `$this->Session->read('Auth.User.id')` vs `$this->Auth->user('id')`

Comment: @user It's the same thing. The AuthComponent stores its data in the session under the `Auth` key. I'd suggest you always use `Auth->user()` for auth data.